# How to assign an argument of a callback to a global variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, callback

I have Some books  in a mongodb database. In order to get information from it to the console, I used:

```
    Books.find().exec((reject,resolve)=>{
     console.log(resolve)
})
```

then I get My array. Although, I want to assign the array to a variable, and show it in the browser, I'm using express, handlebars as a templete engine and body-parser. I already tried to pass other information (not from database), and everything worked just fine. But, when I tried:

```
 let books;
Books.find().exec((reject,resolve)=>{
  books = resolve
});

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index',{books:books});

});


nothing displays in the browser. Then I modified it a bit, and it I got the array, but I don't thing that's the right way of doing it.




 Books.find().exec((reject,resolve)=>{  
            router.get('/',(req,res)=>{ 
   res.render('index',{resolve:resolve});

    });



    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should call the Books.find() inside of the request function.

```
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  Books.find().exec((reject,resolve)=>{
    res.render('index',{books:resolve});
  });
});
```